# Can't install gcc on CentOs 7.0

Tags: centos, software-installation

I have to install gcc on a server that does not have any access to internet due to security issues. I tried ftping the source tar and building it on the server, but it requires gcc to compile gcc. So I downloaded a binary, but I can't untar the tar.xz format. I tried both tar xf and xz but both of them spits out error. Is there any other distributions of gcc binary that is not tarred in .xz format? Or are there any other ways around this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Download the RPMs from http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ and install those with `yum`. Either mirror the whole thing (easiest, really!) or pull down the various dependencies as needed.

You could replicate your secure system on a machine that *can* access the net, `yum install gcc` (or `yum groupinstall` the development group), and then note the list of packages you'll need to add.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not exactly sure how to mirror the whole thing and pull those dependencies from a server without internet. Would I have to ftp the RMPs from another server and then run yum?

Comment: Put them on a USB drive.